# p tags are not breaking when images are floated to the left of them

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to setup paragraphs on my page and float an image to the left of each paragraph and have the text wrap around the floated image.  When I do the paragraph floats properly next to it's image, but the p tags don't break and it just cascades as if everything is inline.

I use these classes throughout my site to float images and it works great everywhere else:

```
.img_left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 1em 0;
}
.img_right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em 20px;
}
```

Here's my code with the exact issue duplicated:
http://jsfiddle.net/MNdpV/

What am I missing?  Thank you!

Comment: Could you place your images within the paragraph of interest?  Also, will you also have images on the right of a paragraph?  Just wondering how many cases to address.

Comment: Weird I thought I tried that! It seems to work. Maybe I forgot to put a space between the image and text?

Comment: Yes that worked!  I bet I carelessly left the space out between the image and text, which left it inline.  If you answer below I will accept.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: You can do it both ways, do you want a solution to both?

Comment: I put the images inside my p tags.

Comment: Try removing the CSS: `width: 920px;` on `.product_pg #content`.

Comment: I shouldn't be floating to the right in this case but thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved your images into their respective `<p>` tags and added `overflow: auto` to the paragraphs
as follows:

```
#content p {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

and this gives the following: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/UEAad/

This is equivalent to clearing your floats.

The advantage of this approach is that it will also work with right floated images.

Setting `overflow: auto` creates a block formatting context, which means any floated child element is constrained to the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `clear: left;` on `img` is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/4gSNt/
(link updated)

`clear: left;` makes the img tag to not align with each other, but crears its line and start from the begining.